# Why is the VSE editor ultra Slow when a scene strip is loaded?

Tags: 3d-view

I need to set up scenes directly in the VSE as a scene Strip. It is possible to visualise the ideas created with Grease Pencil and simple animations of 3-4 planes.That gives me 1 or 2 Fps in the the backdrop of the VSE.

The planes are white. That's it, nothing fancy but the memory go near 700 mb usage.

For one scene strip that shows scene 1 with 3 planes, 30 seconds long and the quadcore Cpu is at 100 % fullpower, blender is nearly a colapsing and ultra slow.

How can I use the scene  strips of blender VSE and what is happening in Blender that makes it so laggy?

Comment: For the scene strip, are you using the OpenGL Preview render? That should speed it up quite a bit. (Although that is the default option already)

Comment: i will try it but its so terrible Slow ?

Comment: in the vSE I try the option Open GL but this bring's only a Frey Screen is the VSE.

Comment: A grey Screen I mean sry ,so next I set the  Open GL option off and that bring's the Standard camera 3D view in the vSE scenestrip  back so i can see the Scene. In the VSE but only with 1 frame/sec .

Comment: Is that open gl. only for blender intern render  ?

Comment: i have 3 face in my scene and a Emission material and a camera that it.

Comment: Nothing is animated a camera show the 3 white faces.So this is send to to VSE as a scenestrip and only viewable when the Open gL is deaktivated .when not always a grey screen appears ...Open gl means that I must pre render this simple looking  scene without movement in Open gL format and then saving it on Disk and reload  the Open GL in the vsE as a picture sequence.or need I the Gameengine for OpenGL in the VSE? I have read the full wiki s theme about VSE but no solution .blender runs so bad Slow with 1 near empty scene (3faces) in VSe as scenestrip 001 I have it Never espected ?

Comment: What a  Monster PC can rum this with 24 frame/sec. I have a good  SSD SYSTEM GOOD ATI 7970  gPU but ONe strip One Scene with 3 faces to kill this PC and bring's the CPU to 100 %.after a try in blender Looks like a joke .I hope this is a BuG.

Comment: Oh and the RAM is near 1 Gb ? The scene strip is 40 sec Long . I dont know unbelievable .how paint a storyborad and show it as scnestrip pre assembled in the VSe.looks impossible.

Comment: I assume you are using Cycles, correct? May I ask for a screenshot of your issue? It's very hard to understand what you are saying (partly because you just keep mentioning your computer specs which won't help us help you).

Comment: You may want to look at setting up [proxies](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage/Proxy_Strip_Properties_Panel)